# Manually reset Windows Service Failure Count

Tags: windows-services, recovery

I configured my Windows Service recovery as following:

- List item
- First failure: Restart the Service
- Second failure: Restart the Service
- Subsequent failures: Take No Action
- Reset fail count after: 1 days
- Restart service after: 1 minutes

Now I would like to reset the failure count after the third failure so that when an admin manually restarts the service, the service can be automatically recovered anew.

So far, the only solution I found is to reset the counter is uninstalling / reinstalling the service which I find not clean. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The service control manager counts the number of times each service has failed since the system booted. The count is reset to 0 if the service has not failed for dwResetPeriod seconds.

Calling [ChangeServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the dwResetPeriod of SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS set to 0 will reset the count.

You will need to query (see [QueryServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) the original setting of dwResetPeriod, set it to zero then reset it back to the original to preserve the state.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I made a tool to change the dwResetPeriod but that didn't work: the count won't reset.   
I tried:   
(a) 1. the service fails for the 3rd time, 2. set dwResetPeriod = 0, 3. set dwResetPeriod = 86400, 4. start the service   
(b) 1. the service fails for the 3rd time, 2. set dwResetPeriod = 0, 3. start the service, 4. set dwResetPeriod = 86400